# Erro WebRequest c#

Tags: c#, delphi, post, http-request

Estou fazendo uma requisição do tipo POST para uma URL, porém sempre recebo como erro a seguinte mensagem "A conexão subjacente estava fechada: Erro inesperado em um envio.".

Esta requisição é feita através de uma dll que crie em C#, que é utilizada pelo Delphi.

O que é mais estranho que se for utilizado este método pelo próprio c# funciona perfeitamente.

Abaixo o código:

```
public string GerarRequisicaoPOST(string Json, string URL, string Autenticacao, out int RetornoStatus)
    {           
        try
        {

            string dadosPOST = Json;

            var dados = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dadosPOST);

            var requisicaoWeb = WebRequest.CreateHttp(URL);

            requisicaoWeb.Method = "POST";
            requisicaoWeb.ContentType = "application/json";
            requisicaoWeb.Accept = "application/json";
            requisicaoWeb.ContentLength = dados.Length;
            requisicaoWeb.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000;
            requisicaoWeb.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0";                
            ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            if (Autenticacao != "")
            {
                requisicaoWeb.Headers["Authorization"] = Autenticacao;//Adicionando o AuthToken  no Header da requisição
            }


            //precisamos escrever os dados post para o stream
            using (var stream = requisicaoWeb.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(dados, 0, dados.Length);
                stream.Close();

            }


            using (var resposta = (HttpWebResponse)requisicaoWeb.GetResponse())
            {

                var streamDados = resposta.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamDados);
                object objResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

                var post = objResponse.ToString();

                var statusCode = resposta.StatusCode;
                RetornoStatus = Convert.ToInt32(statusCode);

                streamDados.Close();
                resposta.Close();

                return post;

            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            RetornoStatus = -1;
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

O mesmo teste feito através do Postman também funciona.

Comment: Onde exatamente você está recebendo a mensagem de erro? Já pensou em trocar o WebRequest por um HttpClient?

Comment: No retorno da requisição feita pelo Delphi.

Comment: E onde está esse código?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver.
Basta colocar

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

antes do

```
var requisicaoWeb = WebRequest.CreateHttp(URL);
```

ficando assim:

```
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var requisicaoWeb = WebRequest.CreateHttp(URL);

            requisicaoWeb.Method = "POST";
            requisicaoWeb.ContentType = "application/json";
            requisicaoWeb.Accept = "application/json";
            requisicaoWeb.ContentLength = dados.Length;
            requisicaoWeb.ReadWriteTimeout = 60000;
            requisicaoWeb.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0";
            requisicaoWeb.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```